# Meteor not updating users database on remote server

Tags: mongodb, meteor, account

I have a project that is utilizing the Meteor accounts package. I have a user signed in with no username field. When I try and update it while it is running on the localhost, using `Meteor.users.update({}, {$set:{username:"Zach Ary"}})` it works beautifully, and the change is reflective via the accounts-ui, and `meteor mongo`. However, when I deploy it to the remote meteor server, and try to update it, no change is shown. Any ideas?

This is the code used on the server (for testing purposes only)

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  update:function(userId, upd) {
    console.log(upd)
    return true;
  }
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is your issue, but on the development server Meteor autopublishes all of your collections.

When you bundle and deploy, you need to manually publish your collections.

Something like this on the server:

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
    });
```

and on the client

```
  Meteor.subscribe("userData")
```

Comment: Yes, but doesn't the Meteor.users database automatically get published (for a given user), and subscribed to?

Comment: It's not related to development server. Meteor autopublish *by default*. So just "meteor remove autopublish" and then it'll work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this caught me off guard. Apparently this has nothing to do with publishing it to the server, rather it was just a misleading coincidence. The problem stems from my update command `Meteor.users.update({}, {$set:{username:"Zach Ary"}})`. For this to work, it needs to be `Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.userId()}, {$set:{username:"Zach Ary"}})`. Otherwise it tries to update the user that was previously logged in. I don't know if this is a bug, or a misunderstood feature, but it seems to do the trick.

Comment: The first update call will just update the first record found in mongo or minimongo.  You should always be precise in term's of what your trying to update.  Always use an id if one is available.


Edit: Woops, this is way old.